# How to resolve "procedure `gds.graph.create.cypher` not found" error

Tags: neo4j

I got this error message :

> There is no procedure with the name `gds.graph.create.cypher` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

I think that the version of neo4j desktop (4.4.5) I'm using isn't compatible with graph data science playground (2.0.3). But I don't know what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the GDS 2.0, the `create` method has been renamed to `project`.

Try

```
Call gds.graph.project.cypher
```

Answer (score 0):

This same error can also be caused by GDS not having been installed.

To install GDS, just specify graph-data-science as a plugin to load during neo4j startup, which will trigger the automatic download of the GDS plugin into /var/lib/neo4j/plugins (persist this volume to avoid re-downloading it each time).

Below is the environment variable example:

```
NEO4J_PLUGINS=["graph-data-science"]
```